# CodeBlocks exe stops working

Tags: c, arrays, char, strcmp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char string;
    printf("Hello\n");
    printf("What would you like to do\n");
    printf("Here are the options\n");
    printf("s : How are you\n");
    printf("c : What would you like to search\n");
    scanf("%s",&string);
    if(string == 'h')
        printf("iam fine\n");

    else if (string == 's')
        printf("What would you like to search\n");
    scanf("%s",&string);
    system(string);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this after it says what would you like to search and I type `run notepad` it stops working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with this scanf:

```
printf("What would you like to search\n");
scanf("%s",&string);
system(string);
```

1. `string` is a single char - the `scanf` will result in a buffer overrun.
2. The `%s` format specifier only reads until the next whitespace.

To fix the problem you should allocate a larger buffer and read an entire line:

```
char buffer[1024];
printf("What would you like to search\n");
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
system(buffer);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1.** defining `string` as `char` won't work for you. you need an array.

define `char string[100] = {0};`

**Problem 2.** `scanf("%s",&string);` not required, can be used as `scanf("%s",string);`

**problem 3.** `if(string == 'h')`, wrong. array contents cannot be compared using `==` operator. you've to use [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) function.

Comment: Keeping `string` as type `char` won't work - OP wants to use it to store the string "notepad", for instance.

Comment: @DanielKleinstein Thanks. I just stopped looking at the very first incorrect instance.